# ASP.Net Core MVC : How to use css after press button in the section of HTML.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

My code are below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostUsingParameters", "loopW"))
{
    <input type="text" name="num" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
}
```

after pressing the button it jumps to the destination page but there is no any CSS effect to the result.

I have tried many ways including using `FormMethod.Post new { @class = "example" }`. Unfortunately, it’s no use to make the CSS take effect in the destination page. Would appreciate some advice on this problem.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, where do you want CSS to applied, just on a submit button or while form is submitting you want to show some CSS effect?

Comment: What's the version of asp.net core you use?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know how to reply the comment. Thus, I answered my own question. Please check my recent answer for all details.

Answer (score 0):

I use .Net 5.0 in my project. Moreover, I want the CSS working on new page after pressing submit button.

```
<head>
...
    <style>
        .example {
            font-size: 70px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <section>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("PostUsingParameters", "loopW", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "example" }))
            {
                <input type="text" name="num" /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: " I want the CSS working on new page ", Why not add `<style>` in the new page too ?